# Simple dropdown list mvc4 retrieve from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a simple drop down list from a query in the database.

I've read so much on this that to be honest I'm so confused. This is probably the best tutorial i've [found](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/128/Get-The-Drop-On-ASP.NET-MVC-DropDownLists)

The model is like this.

```
public class TodoMembership
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public string UserTodoName { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

The controller is simple.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
//connection already sorted
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.TodoMemberships.Select(c => new SelectListItem
               {
                 Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                 Text = c.Category
               });
ViewBag.Categories = items;
return View();
}
```

And this in my html.
     @Html.DropDownList("Id", (IEnumerable) ViewBag.Categories)

This is the error I get,

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 2):

use [**SqlFunctions.StringConvert**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
IEnumerable < SelectListItem > items = db.TodoMemberships.Select(c => new SelectListItem {
    Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double) c.Id),
        Text = c.Category
});
```

Comment: I'm now left with this ..... The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double?)' and 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert(decimal?)'

Comment: Thanks works just as well. I've found new ways today! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.TodoMemberships, "Id", "Category");
```

This way the string conversion will be executed in the application and not on the SQL server.

Comment: Awesome, this worked a treat! Now to work out how to filter results.